# Order status not updated even after Shipping of product

Tags: magento, e-commerce, orders

I have a problem with my magento, when i go to fresh orders it shows Order Status as processing even after when i have generated the invoice and shipped the product it still showing order status processing, it should be automatically changed to Complete, can u help me to resolve it, Citrus Payment Gateway used to placing the order.[image]

Comment: did you get solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Check system -> order statuses there should be complete [Complete] state assign to complete status and also check that complete state should not assigned 2 or more time and also same for processing must be assign one time.

Comment: i have checked everything, complete [Complete] state is only assigned to complete.

everything is happening normally when i disable my payment gateway plugin (Citrus Pay) and make a order using Draft or Cheque option, then all the functionality work as normal. Please help.